# Firebase: Deprecation Warning: Firebase Hosting configuration should be moved under "hosting" key

Tags: firebase-hosting

After upgrading my Firebase project, I got this warning message when deploying my project to Firebase hosting.

`Deprecation Warning: Firebase Hosting configuration should be moved under "hosting" key.`

Anyone has the same problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to modify your **firebase.json** file which I assume looks somewhat like this:

```
{
"public": "dist",
"ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
    {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
    }
]
}
```

You need to move the different keys specified (in this case, `public`, `ignore` and `rewrites` key) to the `hosting` key so the snippet above would look like below.

```
{
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Check out this link for more info on [Firebase hosting deployment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#section-full-firebasejson).

Comment: Thanks for your answer